# Can't install pip and python & ansible using Dockerfile in CentOS

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, ansible, dockerfile

I am trying to install python and pip & Ansible using Dockerfile but I get this error

```
/bin/sh: 1: python: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py &&     python get-pip.py &&     python -m pip install --upgrade "pip < 21.0" &&     pip install ansible --upgrade' returned a non-zero code: 127
ERROR: Service 'jenkins' failed to build : Build failed
```

**Here is my Dockerfile:**

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

USER root



RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py && \
    python get-pip.py && \
    python -m pip install --upgrade "pip < 21.0" && \
    pip install ansible --upgrade





USER jenkins
```

***Note: I used the same instructions on another Dockerfile and it went without errors. Here is the Dockerfile from CentOS image:***

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum update -y && \
    yum -y install openssh-server && \
    yum install -y passwd

RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo "password" | passwd remote_user  --stdin && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh

COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user   -R /home/remote_user && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen

RUN yum -y install mysql

RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py && \
    python get-pip.py && \
    python -m pip install --upgrade "pip < 21.0" && \
    pip install awscli --upgrade

CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Comment: Please do not edit with "solved !". You provided a self answer which is the good way to proceed. You will be able to accept that self answer in a few hours.

Comment: python is not installed in your base image.... why don't you simply install it prior to launching all those python commands ?

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not entirely sure my comments were fully understandable, here is how I would install `ansible` in your current base image `jenkins/jenkins`.

Notes:

- I fixed the tag to `lts` since building from latest is a bit on the edge. You can change that to whatever tag suits your needs.
- That base image is itself based on Ubuntu and not CentOS as reported in your title (hence using `apt` and not `yum/dnf`)
- I used two `RUN` directives (one for installing python, the other for ansible) but you can merge them in a single instruction if you want to further limit the number of layers.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install ansible && \
    pip cache purge

USER jenkins
```

Answer (score -1):

I deleted RUN instructions and replaced it with :

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ansible
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: 1) This is creating 2 layers in your image for a single package installation 2) you are not cleaning up after yourself which leaves all the apt cache in the layers 3) installing ansible with the OS package manager is by far my least recommended option. You will end up with an obsolete ansible version that will most likely never be upgraded and where adding optionnal components might become a pure mess. After checking on your above image, the deployed ansible version is 2.10 where the latest is 2.12. Installing through pip is IMO the most flexible option.

Comment: Thanks so much Zeitounator, as you said this is not recommended, but i have to take your notes